# Inquiry, Is this Crystal?

Tags: geology

I'm Erfan from Yemen, I found this stone in my village's mountain, it looks not normal stone, it's shinning like a crystal and headlight can penetrate it.

There are hundreds of it in the mountain.

Can you tell me please what it's kind, and does it precious stone?

My Regards

[image]

Comment: Your rocks are probably calcite (calcium carbonate) inside an accretion coating. Calcite is too common to have value, but your rocks are an unusual form and may have a small value as curiosities or geological specimens. To test that it is calcite, put some acid on it. If it is calcite, it should fizz.

Comment: Try vinegar if you don't have access to acid! :-) This should cause a weak fizz reaction.